# PIR counter for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, infrared

Thank you for reading this. I am trying to write a Python script that counts how many times a PIR sensor is tripped within a given time interval (1 minute). My issue is that my code is only adding +1 to the count in every loop, regardless of how many times the PIR is tripped and my loop is taking longer than the time interval I assign. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

---

```
from collections import Counter
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN)

counter=0

while True:
    i=GPIO.input(11)
    if i==True:
        counter = counter + 1
        print(counter)   
   time.sleep(60)
```

------SOLUTION-----
If anyone in the future has the same problem here's my solution:

```
from collections import Counter
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN)

while True:     #this will create an infinite loop BUT the next while argument will make each loop interval 60 seconds * 1 minute
    counter=0
    t_end = time.time() + 60 * 1 #60 seconds * 1
    while time.time() < t_end:
        i=GPIO.input(11)
        if i==True:
           counter = counter + 1
    print(counter)
```

Comment: Fix your identation, `time.sleep(60)` is not correctly idented, it would raise an error.

Comment: Your code right now just **checks *every* 60 seconds**. It doesn't **check *for* 60 seconds**

Comment: Try copy and pasting the code you wrote here and run it. You will get an error at `time.sleep(60)`. Is `time.sleep(60)` inside the `while` loop? is it inside the `if` statement. Neither python, nor we can tell. I suppose that it is under the `while` loop. If this is the case, after 1 loop completes (when `GPIO.input` finishes) your program **STOPS** for 60 seconds. In other words the loop is stuck at `time.sleep(60)`. You should remove `time.sleep` completely

Comment: Thank you Countour-Integral! How do you make a while loop run rather than wait for 60 seconds then?

Comment: you are manually checking if the sensor is being tripped right now and then stopping python entirely for 60 seconds. what you should do instead is set up an interrupt so when the sensor is tripped it will tell you. check [this](https://roboticsbackend.com/raspberry-pi-gpio-interrupts-tutorial/#Python_code_with_RPi_GPIO) example. if you just remove the sleep from you current code you will be doing something called a "busy wait" which is needlessly resource intensive

Comment: Nullman: this is an awesome tutorial, thank you!

Comment: as a bonus tip: when reply to comments, make sure to to @ the person you are replying to or they wont know you replied unless they check manually

Comment: @Nullman Thank you! I am definitely a n00b

Comment: @Nullman I just wanted to say thank you so much for that information. That was EXACTLY what I needed to learn. Thank you!!!

Comment: you're welcome. since you didnt get a proper answer you should write an answer to your own question and explain how you fixed it (for the next guy that gets stuck on this)